# How do I synchronise the slider with the ticks so as to make it responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

In [my code so far](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/f5dxq8mj/21/), I have appended the tick markers and labels to the jQuery UI slider. When I increase/decrease the size of the browser window, these ticks go out of sync with the slider.

It is happening because of the following piece of code:

```
$('<span class="ui-slider-tick-mark"> <br/>'+ date[i] +'</span>') // line # 44 in JS
.css('left', (spacing * i - 3.5) +  '%')
.appendTo($slider);
```

I tried to play around with the static value but it seems that as long as this value is static, its not going to be responsive.

I believe that if the first and last tick stays at the start and end of the slider respectively, it will be synchronized.

How do I achieve this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/f5dxq8mj/21/)

Comment: [This plugin might help](http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/). Seems to have responsive behaviour to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't add any additional value to percentage `(spacing * i - 3.5)`
http://jsfiddle.net/f5dxq8mj/22/